# Executable Statements in If Statements

Tags: java

There is an explanatory code of what I'm trying to ask. Sureley, the difference between the codes below is ignorable, yet it describes the point.

Which one is the most efficient in terms of memory usage and performance?

```
if( MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle) > Angles.ACUTE){
     // Something is done
    }
```

or

```
double angleSin = MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle);

if( angleSin > Angles.ACUTE){
// Something is done
}
```

Comment: It depends on if you are going to use `angleSin` somewhere else.

Comment: In that case, option 1.

Comment: Then first approach is better because it limits scope of temporary valriable `angleSin` to `if(...)`.

Comment: Maybe this question should be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @bigdestroyer Nope, sorry. The code would be too short. Code Review is for reviewing working code, not asking about best practice. This question would probably be closed as it presents example code.

Comment: @bigdestroyer, Actually my question is not about the algorithm nor the way I implement it. I'm curious about the memory usage of the approaches, therefore efficiency is the purpose.

Comment: Side note to the 3 persons who voted to close for "primarily opinion based", OP is seeking here for performance and efficiency differences which is nor primarily opinion based at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply depends if you are going to re-use the variable.

- If yes, use the second case.
- If no use the first case.

There is no reason to store the value in a variable if you are not going to re-use it.

**Edit :**

As per your comment, it seems you are mostly asking this question for performance concern...

> Actually my question is not about the algorithm nor the way I
>   implement it. I'm curious about the memory usage of the approaches,
>   therefore efficiency is the purpose.

Don't expect any difference in term of memory usage for both approaches, the JVM and JIT will optimize it as much as possible so that both case become the same.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the other answers, you should also consider readability of your code. In this case, the meaning of `MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle)` is pretty obvious. However, if you have a more complex condition, it would be a good idea to precompute that condition, give the variable a meaningful name and then use the variable in the `if`-statement.

In your case it also depends on the context of the `if`-statement. Again, `MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle) > Angles.ACUTE` is quite easy to grasp at a glance. However,

```
final boolean angleIsAcute = (MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle) > Angles.ACUTE);
if(angleIsAcute) { ... }
```

would carry the meaning better. In this case, of course, both possibilities are quite similar, but I hope you see where I am going with this.

Do not worry about the overhead that is introduced by storing that extra variable. Even though the java-compiler does not optimize your code, any JVM worth its salt will optimize the bytecode and the performance overhead will be negligible.

Comment: An alternate approach would be create a utility class with utility methods such as `isAngleAcute(double angle)` so that such comparisons can be reused across your application. But +1 for the readability advantage that other answers did not cover.

Comment: I also agree that readability win vs micro-optimization (even if there is none in that case), but OP clarified in comments that he was curious about efficiency purpose. Still a good answer as I think it's important for developer to remember that micro-optimizations is not always a good idea. However I would prefer the alternate approach proposed by @ChetanKinger for the re-usability concern.

Comment: I totally agree with your implementation suggestions. I just made up this code from scratch, so that I can demonstrate my point. I appreciate your efforts though. If I have used a boolean method in my example, it would have been harder to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I often use the first pattern even when I won't need the variable later in the code. The advantage is for debugging.

1. You can examine and change the value of the variable when stepping through the code in a debugger.
2. If an exception occurs in the call on the right-hand side of the statement, it is sometimes clearer what happened than if the call is embedded in an `if` or as an argument to another call.

If you're concerned about memory usage for the variable, don't be. Trust the compiler to optimize away variables that it knows aren't going to be used later. If you declare the variable `final`, it will be optimized *aggressively* as [described in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#d5e28922).

Comment: Since all the answers agree that the memory usage won't be any different, using a variable for debugging purposes is enough reason to be on that side. Well said

Comment: @Kevin You can examine statements while stepping through them as well in most IDEs.

Comment: Seeing a variable straight forward in the variables tab VS selecting the statement and clicking "execute statement" to see the result. I think first one is a lot easier and useful.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Do you see the value when hovering over a call embedded in an `if` statement? I've not noticed that in Eclipse, but I'll have to watch for it. Your comment inspired me to add that you can *change* the value as well if it is in its own statement.

Comment: @KevinCondon I seldom find myself debugging applications because I write comprehensive unit tests. I don't like the idea of declaring a variable just because I am too lazy to highlight a statement and inspect (an eclipse feature. shortcut is Ctrl+I) it's result. :). That being said, I don't disagree with you. If you find yourself debugging an application a lot of times, a variable might help. Although, this change should be made temporarily only for debugging.

Comment: @ChetanKinger +1 for comprehensive unit tests. I also don't step through with debuggers all that often. I'm far more likely to add debug log messages. In which case, I would need to ... wait for it ... declare the variable outside the `if` in order to log it. :)

Answer (score 0):

References do take memory. So if you are not going to use `angleSin` anywhere else then second option is what you should go for. Besides it does not pollute the namespace. That is one reason people make `Comparator` as an anonymous class instead of creating a new one. If they do not need to use somewhere else.

Comment: Even though we don't assign "MathUtil.CalculateSin(angle)" to a variable, doesn't the result take memory (exactly like it is a variable) ?